# the case of the missing gems and bundler conflict

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler

Outside of my rails application directory I accidentally ran `bundle install _a_gem_` when I meant `gem install _a_gem`. It has been some long hours. After this I haven't been able to get my environment working. Running `gem list` inside of my application gives me just the _a_gem_ I later installed. Running `gem list` outside of my application gives me my desired gem list and the ones I was originally was using with the app.

(o) outside application directory
(i) inside application directory

which gem

```
/Users/name/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/gem   (o)
/Users/name/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/gem   (i)
```

which irb

```
/Users/name/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/irb   (o)
/Users/name/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/irb   (i)


bundle install (o)
Could not locate Gemfile 

bundle install (i)
/Users/...rubygems/dependency.rb:247:in `to_specs': Could not find bundler (>= 0) amongst [spreadsheet-0.8.2] (Gem::LoadError)
```

gem list
(o) has all gems (i) has just _a_gem_ from within my rails app.

The gems/bundler commands work fine just about anywhere but inside the application directory. I tried reinstalling bundler but got a conflict:

(i)

```
/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:1603:in    `raise_if_conflicts': can't activate bundler-1.3.0, already activated bundler-1.0.21 (Gem::LoadError)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

EXTRA:
The trace from when I `gem install bundler` then try a bundler command such as `bundle install`

```
/Users/name/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:1603:in `raise_if_conflicts': can't activate bundler-1.3.0, already activated bundler-1.0.21 (Gem::LoadError)
from /Users/name/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:738:in `activate'
from /Users/name/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1211:in `gem'
from /Users/name/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/bundle:18:in `<main>'
```

UPDATE: `gem env` output inside and outside of directory

https://gist.github.com/yuric/5069049

Comment: Could you print out `gem env` both inside and outside the dir?

Comment: do you have any .rvm file in the (i) dir? what happens when you `ls -a` it? perhaps an `.rvmrc` file?

Comment: not anything rvm related that I can tell. I do have a .bundle

Comment: let me see it's content :-)

Comment: only config inside the .bundle folder here it is:---
BUNDLE_PATH: roo
BUNDLE_DISABLE_SHARED_GEMS: '1'

Comment: do you have a Gemfile in the (i) dir? try in the (i) dir `rvm gemset use global`

Comment: I have a gem file in the (i) application directory after running the command above and trying `bundle install` I get `/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby: no such file to load -- bumbler/go (LoadError)`. Cannot run `gem instal bundler` either. `<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require': no such file to load -- bumbler/go (LoadError)
 from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'`

Comment: gem list command is not working now in  (i)

Comment: in (i) dir try `rvm gemset use global` and then try bundler

Comment: I did that and got the errors above. .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global that is pretty much empty inside. .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290 has all the gems

Comment: after `rvm gemset use global` bundler commands still do not work. Gem commands stopped working also (`ex. gem list`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found this set of instructions invaluable for resolving bundler issues:

```
# remove user-specific gems and git repos
rm -rf ~/.bundle/ ~/.gem/

# remove system-wide git repos and git checkouts
rm -rf $GEM_HOME/bundler/ $GEM_HOME/cache/bundler/

# remove project-specific settings and git repos
rm -rf .bundle/

# remove project-specific cached .gem files
rm -rf vendor/cache/

# remove the saved resolve of the Gemfile
rm -rf Gemfile.lock

# try to install one more time
bundle install
```

Here's a link to the original page on github where I ran across these. They normally resolve bundler issues for me.

https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/blob/1-0-stable/ISSUES.md

Comment: it is bringing up: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby

Comment: from line above, is it using ruby 1.8 for some reason? Ruby -v list 1.9.2 though

Comment: What do you get if you type `rvm list` from the application directory?

Comment: ruby 1.9.2
Ok, I am on my way. I followed your link, run the commands above, restarted the computer a couple times after deleting a couple cached gem files in the gem directory and now bundler is working again. Thank you so much.